# jQuery interact with appended data

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here? I'm trying to interact with data (appended using ajax)

The alerts fire if the element is already in DOM, but not when It's appended.

Am I using the ".on" wrong?

```
$(function() {

  $('.card').on('click','.add-exercise', function() {
    alert('clicked');
  });

  // Detect 'enter' key up
  $('#search').on('keyup', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13)
    {
      console.log('hit enter key');
      $(this).trigger("enterKey");
    }
  });

  $('#search').on("enterKey",function(e){

    $.ajax({
      url: '{{ url("exercises/load") }}',
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        _token: "{{csrf_token()}}",
        search: $('#search').val(),
      },
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('.exercise-result').remove();
        $('.card-deck').append(data);
      }
    });

  });

});
```

Comment: share the data that you are appending

Comment: try   `$(document).on('click','.card .add-exercise',` or `$('.card-deck').on('click','.card .add-exercise',`

Comment: thanks @PranavCBalan $(document) worked great!

Comment: glad to help ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `.card` element is also loading dynamically, in order to make [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) works properly you need to bind it to an element which is present at the time of page load.

So either you can attach it to the `document` object.

```
$(document).on('click','.card .add-exercise', function(){ 
   // rest of your code
});
```

or better approach would be, attach to an element which is present at the time of page load(I guess `.card-deck` is present at the time of page load since you are appending data to that or attach to `body` tag).

```
$('.card-deck').on('click','.card .add-exercise', function(){ 
   // rest of your code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have other `.card` elements in `data`.

You have to assign the event `click` again for them. The event is currently only assigned to your first `.card` elements. This is why it doesn't fire on your new `.card` elements.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to add the event again each time the append is done. Try this and let me know if it works:

```
function addEvent() {
  $('.card').on('click','.add-exercise', function() {
    alert('clicked');
  });
}

$(function() {
  addEvent();

  // Detect 'enter' key up
  $('#search').on('keyup', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13)
    {
      console.log('hit enter key');
      $(this).trigger("enterKey");
    }
  });

  $('#search').on("enterKey",function(e){

    $.ajax({
      url: '{{ url("exercises/load") }}',
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        _token: "{{csrf_token()}}",
        search: $('#search').val(),
      },
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('.exercise-result').remove();
        $('.card-deck').append(data);
        addEvent();
      }
    });

  });

});
```

Comment: No need to keep attaching the search event

Comment: True, adjusted.